# E/chromium: [ERROR:compositor_impl_android.cc(585)] Failed to init OutputSurface for compositor

Tags: android, android-studio

I use XWalkView. My app works well on devices earlier than Android 10.
After updating the target version to 29, my application does not work on android 10.

I am getting the below errors.

```
E/chromium: [ERROR:compositor_impl_android.cc(585)] Failed to init OutputSurface for compositor.
A/chromium: [FATAL:compositor_impl_android.cc(586)] Too many context creation failures. Giving up...
A/libc: Fatal signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -1 (SI_QUEUE) in tid 16379
```

build.gradle file

```
 dependecies{
implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.+'
implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.+'
implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.+'
x86Implementation files('libs/xwalk_core_library-23.53.589.4.aar')
x64Implementation files('libs/xwalk_core_library-23.53.589.4-64bit.aar')
```

...

```
compileSdkVersion 29
buildToolsVersion '29.0.2'
defaultConfig {
    applicationId ".."
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 29
    versionCode 6
    versionName "1.0.3"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
```

Comment: Hi, did you solve this problem, Nur?

Comment: Hello, I solved the problem using Android WebView.

Comment: @NurARSLAN yeah, that would also do it, since webview is internal.

Comment: Be careful with the internal Android WebView. Samsung tends to modify their internals to disgusting levels, often breaking internal WebView very badly. Users assume it's your app's fault, and then leave a bad review. I really hope someone can find a solution to this problem.

Comment: Not a full answer just yet, but I found [this repo which appears to have pulled it off](https://github.com/ks32/CrosswalkNative). With a bit of luck we might be able to adapt this to other XWalk projects.